# ¿Como tomar los micro servicios de una pagina web con java?

Tags: java

Se necesita tomar los micro servicios de un sitio web con java, estos se ven así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o también se pueden tomar de los scripts en el html, que librería de java podría usar para tomar esta información de varias Urls de forma dinámica?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No es muy clara tu pregunta.. podrias usar el boton [edit] y aclarar mucho mejor que necesitas y que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: ¿Qué significa "tomar los microservicios"?

Comment: Me refiero a tomar las url de los micro servicios que se usan en la pagina